Bound on the radon-nikodym derivative between two stochastic processes at a time point
I have two stochastic differential equations on $\mathbb{R}^d$ adapted to the same filtration evolving for finite time $t\in [0, T]$ at the same start distribution:
\begin{align*}
dX_t &= b(t, X_t) + \sqrt{2}dW_t\\
dY_t &= b'(t, Y_t) + \sqrt{2}dW_t,
\end{align*}
Let $\mu_t, \nu_t$ respectively denote their distributions. It is known that for every $t\in [0, T]$, $b(t, \cdot) = b'(t, \cdot)$ for every $x\in B_t$ for some collection of sets $B_t$ and $\|b(t, \cdot) - b'(t, \cdot)\|_{L^2(\mu_t)}\le \epsilon$.
Suppose we know that $\Pr[Y_t\in B_t] \ge 1 - \delta$ where $\delta > 0$ is small. Is it possible to show that
$$\left\|\frac{d\mu_t}{d\nu_t}\right\|_{L^\infty}\le M < \infty$$ uniformly in time, and if so what would be a big-O bound on $M$? If not, is it possible to get a bound of the following form:
$$\mu_t\left\{x \,\bigg|\, \left|\frac{d\mu_t}{d\nu_t}\right|\le M\right\} \ge 1- \text{ something}$$
while still providing a big-O bound on $M$?
Ideally, there should be no (Lipschitz) assumptions on $b, b'$ other than that they do not blow up in the interval $[0, T]$, but it's fine if there are Lipschitz assumptions.
I feel like it should somehow be possible to use Girsanov, but it's not clear.

There are no quantifiers on $t$. If it's just meant to be fixed, then this obviously cannot hold ($B_s$ could just be empty for $s < t$ and the drifts could be wildly different).
